# CSS Table margin for cell

Tags: html, css, html-table

I want to have a `table` that has the layout of a left floated cell a right floated cell and the middle cell to stay in the center.

Example: [image]

**Problem:** When the data inside the middle cell increases it moves more to the left thus decreasing the margin I want between the cells.

Example: [image]

**Code:**

```css
.settings {
  /*background: #636969;*/
  width: 750px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 1em;
}
.settings h4 {
  padding: 1em 0;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #cacece;
}
.settings table {
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 0.9em;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  font-weight: 200;
}
.settings tr {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #cacece;
}
.settings td {
  padding: 0.5em 0;
}
.settings .edit {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<!-- start settings -->
<div class='settings'>
  <h4>Account Settings</h4>
  <table class='options'>
    <tr>
      <td class='name username'>Name</td>
      <td class='value'>Robert Rocha</td>
      <td class='edit'><a href='#'>Edit</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class='name email'>Email</td>
      <td class='value'>unitedstatesofamerica@gmail.com</td>
      <td class='edit'><a href='#'>Edit</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class='name pword' colspan='2'>Password</td>
      <td class='edit'><a href='#'>Edit</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
<!-- end settings -->
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/24moy4rc/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simply add `table-layout:fixed` to your `table`

```css
.settings {
  /*background: #636969;*/
  width: 750px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 1em;
}
.settings h4 {
  padding: 1em 0;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #cacece;
}
.settings table {
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 0.9em;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  font-weight: 200;
  table-layout: fixed;
}
.settings tr {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #cacece;
}
.settings td {
  padding: 0.5em 0;
}
.settings .edit {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div class='settings'>
  <h4>Account Settings</h4>
  <table class='options'>
    <tr>
      <td class='name username'>Name</td>
      <td class='value'>Robert Rocha</td>
      <td class='edit'><a href='#'>Edit</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class='name email'>Email</td>
      <td class='value'>unitedstatesofamerica@gmail.com</td>
      <td class='edit'><a href='#'>Edit</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class='name pword' colspan='2'>Password</td>
      <td class='edit'><a href='#'>Edit</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: I have to wait a couple minutes until it lets me.

Answer (score 0):

you can set a fixed width for the first column:

```
.name { width: 100px; }
```

see here: https://jsfiddle.net/dojprwzL/

Answer (score 0):

Use

`.settings table{table-layout:fixed;}`

or 
You can use width of each cell in percentages like

```
        .settings td{word-wrap: break-word;}        
        td:first-child{width:30%;}
        td:nth-child(2){width:40%;}
        td:last-child{width:30%;}
```

Check [**Updated Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/Rayudu/24moy4rc/5/)

Answer (score 0):

You've already done it for your edit column by doing so:

```
.settings .edit {
  text-align: right;
}
```

This puts the content in your edit column straight to the right hand side. What you need to do is just to add the same rule for your other columns, obviously replacing `right` through `left` and `center`. That being said your styling would look somehow like this:

```
.settings .name {
  text-align: left;
}

.settings .value {
  text-align: center;
}

.settings .edit {
  text-align: right;
}
```

A live example can be seen [here](https://jsfiddle.net/24moy4rc/3/).

Comment: Although this is one way to do it, it ruins the middle text in that it is in the middle but while being in the middle the text is not left aligned as shown in the picture above; the middle text looks like a pyramid.